# Android addView not working when called in another thread?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-view

I have a simple kotlin android app where I have a GridLayout View where I then programmatically add views to it. This works fine if I just call it in the onCreate method as so:

```kotlin
findViewById<GridLayout>(R.id.gridLayout).addView(Button(this))
```

But if I call it in another thread, in my case it is in a `CompletableFuture.runAsync` in an `forEach` loop it stops working. I tried to look with the LayoutInspector but no views are getting added to the GridLayout. I also tried debugging to see if the code is even reached and yes, it was reached and executed but no luck.
I also tried to save the `Context` in the onCreate to re-use it in the other thread to create the Views but no luck there either.

Has anyone ever had a similar issue?

This is the code that doesn't work for reference:

```kotlin
        val gridLayout = findViewById<GridLayout>(R.id.gridLayout)
        savedPics.forEach { (picture, bytearray) ->
            val cardView = CardView(context)
            val param = GridLayout.LayoutParams(
                GridLayout.spec(
                    GridLayout.UNDEFINED, GridLayout.FILL, 1f
                ),
                GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, GridLayout.FILL, 1f)
            )
            param.height = 0
            param.width = 0
            cardView.layoutParams = param

            val verticalLinearLayour = LinearLayout(context)

            verticalLinearLayour.layoutParams =
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
            verticalLinearLayour.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL



            val imageView = ImageView(context)
            val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytearray, 0, bytearray.size)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)

            val textView = TextView(context)
            textView.layoutParams = LayoutParams(android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
            textView.text = picture.image_name

            verticalLinearLayour.addView(imageView)
            verticalLinearLayour.addView(textView)

            cardView.addView(verticalLinearLayour)

            cardView.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(context, ViewPicture::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("picture", picture)
                intent.putExtra("image_array", bytearray)
                startActivity(intent)
            }

            gridLayout.addView(verticalLinearLayour)
        }
```

Comment: Android forbids interacting with views from any thread besides the main thread.

Comment: You can switch to the main thread from another thread when you need to interact with the UI.

Comment: Are you using admob

Answer (score 0):

Ok the issue was that it wasn't being added in the UI thread. To make it run in the UI thread just use `runOnUiThread`.

Too bad there isn't even an error message or anything indicating wrong doing.